# Windows Process Activation Service not starting error 3

Tags: c#, iis-7.5, windows-server-2012

I tried to start the 'Windows Process Activation Service' in services.msc for a new windows2012 server and I was facing the error:

> windows process activation service not starting error 3

Comment: Hello Sudhan. Somehow your question survived 7 years in its original form with a solution inside it. That doesn't match the Q & A format of the site so I moved your solution to an answer below (as a Community Wiki). If you wish to post it yourself, ping me and I will delete the CW answer

Answer (score 6):

For me, I didn't have `ConfigIsolationPath` in my registry, but the Windows Process Activation Service was looking for `c:\inetpub\temp\apppools\`, which I did not have. Creating this folder got things going again. This article was very helpful in tracking down the problem, "[Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) Is Stopping Because It Encountered An Error](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FixedWindowsProcessActivationServiceWASIsStoppingBecauseItEncounteredAnError.aspx)".

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. I did analysis before using ProcMon and it say missing the path not found.

Comment: Great... Creating all the folders in path: "C:\inetpub\temp\apppools"  worked for me as well. Thanks @Doug.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have ConfigIsolationPath in my registry either. Turns out i didn't have enough space on my C:\ drive to restart the services. And the event viewer didn't have any mention of this. I freed up 2GB of space on C:\ drive and then restarted the W3SVC service in Services, and then did an IISRESET, and that seemed to fix my issues.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>the following was posted originally as part of the question. Edited out of the question and into an answer:</sup>

---

1. Open RegEdit
2. Move to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WAS\Parameters`
3. Check the `ConfigIsolationPath` and make sure the path is present and it has proper rights.

Now open `services.msc` and try starting the service. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the `machine.config` which was causing the error.

How I fixed it:

1. Goto `\%SystemRoot%\Microsoft .NET\Framework\%VersionNumber%\CONFIG\`
2. Make a copy of the file `machine.config.default`
3. Remove the default extension to make it `machine.config`
4. Open services and double click on Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) to start it.

I did it for 2.0.xxx.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an event viewer error here but if anyone is dealing with WAS issue recorded by Event ID 7023, here is what helped me:

1. Check c:/windows/system32/inetsrv/ folder. applicationHost.config file might be missing or it might be empty. If that’s the case, go to c:/inetpub/history/ Folder and copy the applicationHost.config file from here to c:/windows/system32/inetsrv/ folder. Try to start Windows Process Activation Service again
2. Go to c:\inetpub\temp\ folder. Check if there is an apppools folder. If there is not, create this folder. Try to start Windows Process Activation Service again
3. Open registry editor. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WAS\Parameters`. Delete NanoSetup entry. Try to start Windows Process Activation Service again
4. Go to c:/windows/system32/inetsrv/ folder. Duplicate applicationHost.config file. Name the new file applicationHost.config.tmp. Try to start Windows Process Activation Service again

Source: [Event ID 7023: The Windows Process Activation Service terminated (System cannot find the file specified)](https://port135.com/2020/08/01/event-id-7023-windows-process-activation-service-terminated/)